# Jenkins Diamond Dependency with Passed Parameter

Tags: jenkins

I would like to be able to set up dependencies between my builds like so:

```
B ---> D
^      ^
|      |
A ---> C
```

Where A is passed a date parameter. Which is passed to B and C, and then to D.

I know there is the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). This, for example, lets me configure in `A`: "when finished, run `B` and `C` with my parameters"

But I don't understand how I then make `D` wait until both `B` and `C` are finished **and** get passed the parameter.

How do I achieve this?

More info: `A` will run periodically, it has a date parameter on it which defaults to the current date. I want this date to be passed to the downstream jobs in case they run on the following day.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a parameterized pipeline, with a date parameter `asof`, and the following pipeline script:

```groovy
node {
    echo "${asof}"
    build(job: "A", parameters: [string(name: "asof", value: "${asof}")]) 
    parallel(
        "B": {
            build(job: "B", parameters: [string(name: "asof", value: "${asof}")]) 
        },
        "C": {
            build(job: "C", parameters: [string(name: "asof", value: "${asof}")]) 
        }
    )
    build(job: "D", parameters: [string(name: "asof", value: "${asof}")]) 
}
```